# code is not reprinting board after initial print.. 2x2 Dots and Boxes game

Tags: printing, mips

The below code is a one player 2x2 Dots and Boxes Game. It prints the board at first and waits for the user input. After that, it simply does not print the board but successfully asks the question. Any insight?

```
.data

board:      .ascii   "\n\n   . . .          . 0 . 1 ."
            .ascii     "\n                  2   3   4"
            .ascii     "\n   . . .          . 5 . 6 ."
            .ascii     "\n                  7   8   9"
            .asciiz    "\n   . . .          . a . b .\n"

intro:      .asciiz     "\n One-Player 2x2 Dots-and-Boxes Game.\n"
prompt:     .asciiz     "\n Please Enter Next Move. (0..b): "   
contPrompt: .asciiz     "\n Would you like to Continue? (y/n): "
newGame:    .asciiz     "\n New Game? (y/n): "
wrongMove:  .asciiz     "\n---------Wrong Move-----------\n"
duplMove:   .asciiz     "\n--------Duplicate Move--------\n"

accept:     .asciiz     "y"
end:        .asciiz     "b"

buffer:     .space      2

addr:       .byte       6,   8,  33,  35,  37,  62,  64,  89,  91,  93,  118, 120
mark:       .byte       '-', '-', '|', '|', '|', '-', '-', '|', '|', '|', '-', '-'


.text

main:   
    la $a0, intro
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    j game

game:
    # Printing the Board    
    la $a0, board
    li $v0, 4
    syscall 
    # Printing Prompt for Value
    la $a0, prompt
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    # Reading Input Values
    li $v0, 8
    la $a0, buffer
    li $a1, 2
    syscall
    # Checking for Validity
    lb $t0, end
    lb $t1, buffer
    bgt $t1, $t0, error
    lb $t0, buffer
    j placePiece


placePiece:
    # Placing Values    
    lb $t1, addr($t0)
    lb $t2, mark($t0)
    sb $t2, board($t1)
    j printBoard

printBoard:
    la $a0, board
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    j con

con:    
    la $a0, contPrompt
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    li $v0, 8
    la $a0, buffer
    li $a1, 2
    syscall
    lb $t0, accept
    lb $t1, buffer
    beq $t0, $t1, game
    j exit


error:
    la $a0, wrongMove
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    j game

exit:
    la $a0, newGame
    li $v0, 4
    syscall 
    la $a0, buffer
    li $a1, 2
    li $v0, 8
    syscall
    lb $t0, accept
    lb $t1, buffer
    beq $t0, $t1, main
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are writing '\0' at the beginning of board.

It seems that you read an ASCII code and then read a look up table using that ASCII code as the index. You should subtract the ASCII code '0' for the digits and subtract ('a'-10) for the letters 'a' and 'b'. Note there is a gap between ASCII code '9' and ASCII code 'a'.

You may as well change the last two board moves to `':'` and `';'` as they are next to `'9'` in the ASCII table.

So, assuming you change `'a'` with `':'` and `'b'` with `';'` you would need to subtract `'0'` before jumping to `placePiece`, e.g.:

```
  lb $t0, buffer
  subiu $t0, $t0, '0'   # convert to array index
  j placePiece
```